# X-CUBE-AI Object Detection Model - STM32H745I-DISCO

Tags: stm32cubeide, stm32h7

I'm currently working on a TinyML project and I'm using a STM32H745I-DISCO with X-CUBE-AI 8.1.0 version. I'm facing a problem when understanding how to change the input of a Mobilenet object detection TFlite model. I would like to modify the code for the input to be an image instead of those random numbers, and then see the predictions.

How should I get the predictions when the input of the model is an image or a dataset? B.t.w. I tried to do a Validation on target but the console output would give me just "Invalid firmware COM19:115200 ...". Does anybody have the same problem?

Thank you in advance.